# SQL Separating big fields for speeding up queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let's say I have a table BOOK:

```
BOOK_ID INT(6) PK
--------------------
FILE_EXTENSION VARCHAR(5)
TITLE VARCHAR(60)
LANGUAGE VARCHAR(10)
EDITION INT(2)
PUBLISHMENT_OFFICE_ID INT(4)
PUBLISH_YEAR INT(4)
RATING INT(1)
FILE_UPDOAD_DATE DATE
LINK VARCHAR(150)
```

This table is meant to be used both for searching books (for ex. by extension, by publishment office, by authors (from other tables), etc) and for full visualization (print on page all books with all these fields).

So there is a question: For example, if I do

```
SELECT BOOK_ID FROM BOOK WHERE FILE_EXTENSION = 'PDF'
```

will this cause the load of all big fields (link, title, and maybe planned BLOB) as an intermediate result, or will it discard any unnecessary fields as soon as WHERE clause is translated with no performance issues?

The question leads for solution: separate big fields in other table with same PK in order to slow down visualization (cuz a JOIN is needed) but to speed up the search? Is it worth?

P.S. This particular DB is not meant to hold rly big amount of data, so my queries (I hope) won't be as slow. But this question is about general databases' design (let's say 10^8 entries).

P.P.S. Pls don't link me to database normalization (my full DB is normilized well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns are stored as part of their row.  Rows are stored as part of a Page.  If you need one column from one row you need to read the whole row, in fact you read the whole page that row is in.  That's likely to be thousands of rows, including all of their columns.  Hopefully that page also has other rows you are interested in and the read isn't wasted.

That's why Columnar databases are becoming so popular for analytics.  They store columns separately.  They still store the values in Pages.  So you read thousands of rows off the disk for that column, but in analytics you're likely to be interested in all or most of those rows.  This way you can have hundreds of columns, but only ever read the columns you're querying.

***MySQL doesn't have ColumnStore.  So, you need an alternative.***

First is to have your large fields in a separate table, which you've already alluded to.

Second, you can use a covering index.

If you index `(file_extension, book_id)` the query `SELECT book_id FROM book WHERE file_extension = 'pdf'` can be satisfied just be reading the index.  It never needs to read the table itself.  *(Indexes are still stored as pages on the disk, but only the columns the index relates to, and potentially a row pointer.  Much narrower than the table.)*

That's a bit clunky though, because the covering index needs to cover the columns you know you'll be interested in.

In practice, your fields are small enough to not warrant this attention until it actually becomes a problem.  It would be wise to store `BLOB`s in a separate table though.

Comment: Ty kindly! Could you also describe the memory cost of holding several indexes (8-10), comparing to size of large table?

Comment: @AlexLarionov - I recommend googling it, or asking another question :)

Comment: MariaDB has ColumnStore.

Answer (score 0):

"Columns are stored as part of their row." -- Yes and no.  All the 'small' columns are stored together in the row.  But `TEXT` and `BLOB`, when 'big', are stored elsewhere.  (This assumes `ENGINE=InnoDB`.)

`SELECT book_id FROM ... WHERE ext = 'PDF'` would benefit from `INDEX(ext, book_id)`.  Without such, the query necessarily scans the entire table (100M rows?).  With that index, it will be very efficient.

"print on page all books with all these fields" -- Presumably this excludes the bulky columns?  In that case `SELECT book_id` versus `SELECT all-these-fields` will cost about the same.  This is a reasonable thing to do on a web page -- *if* you are not trying to display thousands of books on a single page.  That becomes a "bad UI" issue, more than an "inefficient query" issue.

`title` and `link` are likely to come under the heading of "small" in my discussion above.  But any `BLOBs` are very likely to be "big".

Yes, it is *possible* to do "vertical partitioning" to split out the big items, but that is mostly repeating what InnoDB is already doing.  Don't bother.

100M rows is well into the arena where we should discuss these things.  My comments so far only touch the surface.  To dig deeper, we need to see the real schema and some of the important queries.  I expect some queries to be slow.  With 100M rows, improving one query sometimes hurts another query.